# Visual Studio 2013 User-Defined Keyword Scope Issues

Tags: c++, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2013, user-defined-types

I'm working on a C++ project with VS2013 Express and I'm having a problem with syntax highlighting.

It's a pretty low-level embedded project, so I'm working with some `stdint.h` types such as `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` fairly regularly. Visual Studio won't highlight these types by default, so I created some user keywords for the types I'm using all over the place.

My problem is that Visual Studio only seems to highlight the keywords in certain contexts. [Here's a link to what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlwOs.png)

[image]

Visual Studio has no problems highlighting the keywords in the global scope of my file, but inside the function definition and function body the keywords are no longer highlighted.

Is there any workaround for this? The Font and Colors configuration in Visual Studio's options seem to be as language-neutral as possible and have no mention of scoping, and none of the C/C++ options seem to address this. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `Visual Assist X` plugin.

Comment: Are you sure that otherwise, your code is correct? From the screenshot i can see that `SAFETY_PDU` is highlighted like it's something wrong with it (sorry if I'm mistaken - i don't have windows). It could be source of your problems with syntax highlighting.

Comment: Yes, there is an error in the code. Most likely `SAFETY_PDU` is not declared.